# How to reshape specific row record in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have table like this stored in PostgreSQL:

[image]

In my case, i need to select specific row (for example ID = 1), then reshape that selected row, so the output will be like this:

[image]

Is possible to do this logic in single sql query? Someone told me to use "crosstab" but i can't figure out the way to solve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might just suggest `union all`:

```
select 2010 as id_year, A_2010 as a, b_2010 as b from t
union all
select 2011 as id_year, A_2011 as a, b_2011 as b from t
union all
select 2012 as id_year, A_2012 as a, b_2012 as b from t
union all
select 2013 as id_year, A_2013 as a, b_2013 as b from t;
```

However, a lateral join might be more efficient:

```
select v.*
from t, lateral
     (values (2010, A_2010, B_2010), (2011, A_2011, B_2011),
             (2012, A_2012, B_2012), (2013, A_2013, B_2013)
     ) v(id_year, A, B);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t(id, A_2010,A_2011,A_2012,A_2013,B_2010,B_2011,B_2012,B_2013) as ( values
    (1,'value 1','value 4','value 7','value 10','value 13','value 16','value 19','value 21')
)
select
    unnest(array[2010,2011,2012,2013]) as "ID_YEAR",
    unnest(array[A_2010,A_2011,A_2012,A_2013]) as "A",
    unnest(array[B_2010,B_2011,B_2012,B_2013]) as "B"
from t
where id = 1
;
 ID_YEAR |    A     |    B     
---------+----------+----------
    2010 | value 1  | value 13
    2011 | value 4  | value 16
    2012 | value 7  | value 19
    2013 | value 10 | value 21
```